# LCD monitor got wet

Tags: display, lcd

If an LCD monitor got wet because of rain, can it still be used or fixed?
I haven't tried plugging it in yet, since it only got wet yesterday and I don't have the appropriate tools to open it up so that I could dry it. 
Is it the monitor or my desktop that's causing the problem?

Comment: Just wanted to comment how disappointed I am that spending 200 dollars on a monitor does not get me a product that takes into account some moisture getting on it.  I had my LG 24 inch get a bit wet in the rain and now after an hour of working on it, gradually see more horizontal lines creeping in like it's going to short so unplugged as soon as I read this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Best thing to do is let it dry for 5-7 days in an air conditioned room. Then see if it still works. No need to open it up.

Comment: why air conditioned room?

Comment: lower humidity.

Comment: Air conditioners partly work by sucking the water out of the air. This allows more water to evaporate out of the monitor into the air, through the air conditioner.

Comment: A bit late to ask, but can I use a hair dryer to expedite the process, or it's too dangerous?

Answer (score 4):

Depends on how much rain and what internal components got wet. Best bet let it dry and plug it in.

Comment: +1, but I'll add to let it dry _thoroughly_ - much longer than you think it needs.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely let it dry for at least a week.  If possible, completely submerge it in rice (I know, that's a lot of rice), which will help dry it out.  Make sure it looks completely dry from everything you can tell before you try to plug it in.

Answer (score 0):

Rain is usually reasonably pure water and therefore nothing like as corrosive as carbonated drinks or fruit juices. If you don't want to be without your machine for a week you can accelerate evaporation significantly by leaving a desk fan on at the side of it. If you aren't worried about invalidating a warranty then you could consider getting some tools to open up the case. You might also consider using a hairdryer on low heat. If you do that, don't hold it too close or keep in in one spot long enough to heat anything up too much. Tke particular care to dry switches etc and anywhere where water might hide. Be sure that everything is really dry before you connect the power.

If you do spill liquids on PC components, disconnect them right away - don't stop to power the machine down. On a laptop, get the battery out fast. Open things up to access places where the spilled liquid might be lurking, but don't open any power supplies or high voltage components. Soak up any pools of liquid then use clean water to flush corrosive liquids away then dry thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Open the screen and let the inside be exposed to open air for a while. Depending on the humidity of your place the water will evaporate slowly. *Remember* if anything strange happens disconnect the power fast as water with ions is a very good conductor of electricity and can cause a short circuit.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question, the asker can not open the device do to lack of tools.

Answer (score 0):

The wind suggestion:

Have a desk fan blow directly at it for 7 days. Then, buy some tools, and then open the lcd screen to see if it's completely dry. If not, repeat the process, but this time, don't buy tools because you already have.

The soak suggestion:

Get a sponge from your kitchen(of course you have one) and buy some tools to open lcd screen. Then, open the lcd screen, and then you have to try to use the sponge, soak as much water as you can. Try not to touch the battery, or else you'll get electrocuted and that can hurt your skin tremendously. If needed, repeat the process, but this time you don't have to buy tools because you have.

The heat suggestion:

For this suggestion, get a 1000 Watt hairdryer. If you have a lot of water on the lcd, and they won't get away(it's mostly sticky stuff with little water), use high heat, at 212 F, to evaporate the water. But then the sticky stuff will still be left behind. Get a can of water, and try to put just the right amount of water to rinse the glue off(It's hard, too little will leave glue, too much will need to repeat the process again). Then try to examine the motherboard with a see-through lens, which can see through objects. This can lead to overheating. Make sure the CPU is under 100 F.

The dry suggestion:

Open the screen in the computer, set your dehumidifier to at least 122 F. Make sure the dehumidifier points directly to the screen. This will soak the water out, but this can overheat the CPU, so make sure the CPU temperature is 100 F or less. If it hides really close to getting in the screen, set the dehumidifier very close, around 6 inches away or less, but that could burn your monitor.